# Still Freezing when using PyQt4 Thread

Tags: multithreading, pyqt, midi

Despite using a QThread, the GUI is still freezing

(code posted at end) 
The space bar is hit which starts playing midi notes by creating the thread and emitting calls to the play function

```
if self.playing is False:
    # PlayThread is initiated in PianoRoll when the space bar is hit. 
    Loop iterates and plays data, freezing the GUI

else:
    # This section is not reached because another space bar hit cannot be received while data is looping
```

I have viewed the following tutorials and a variety of responses on StackOverflow:

1. https://manojbits.wordpress.com/2013/01/24/threading-in-pyqt4/
2. the joplaete tutorial

I've tried the following:

1. placing all looping code to run in the signaled function
2. placing the loop in the thread's run function and passing the data to the signaled function with emit
3. separating the function from the widget that handling the calls to it
4. making the data structures global (trying anything)

Please let me know what I am missing or if any other code is needed.

I am using an open source MIDI sequencer template
    https://github.com/rhetr/seq-gui

```
class PlayThread(QtCore.QThread):

    def __init__(self):

        # qtcore.QThread.__init__(self, parent=app)

        super(PlayThread , self).__init__()

        self.signal = QtCore.SIGNAL("signal")

    def run(self):

        global xLocToNoteItems

        # this loop was attempted in the signaled function as well
        for xloc in xLocToNoteItems:

            self.emit(self.signal, xloc)

        # self.emit(self.signal, "arbitrary?")

        # self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('update(QString)') + str(i))
```

## in piano roll:

```
if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Space:

    if self.playing:

        self.playing = False

        # terminate play thread

        main.playThread.quit()

    else:

        self.playing = True

        # playThread previously attempted to be stored in this (piano roll) class
            # ...was moved to main in case the call was freezing the piano roll
        main.playThread = PlayThread()

    main.connect(main.playThread, main.playThread.signal, main.play)

    main.playThread.start()
```

## the play function was in the piano roll widget, now in main

```
def play(self, xloc):

    # for xloc in main.xLocToNoteItems:


    global xLocToRhythms
    global xLocToNoteItems

    for noteItem in xLocToNoteItems[xloc]:

        player.note_on(noteItem.note[0], noteItem.note[3], 1)

    offtime = xLocToRhythms[xloc]

    time.sleep(offtime)

    for noteItem in xLocToNoteItems[xloc]:

        player.note_off(noteItem.note[0], noteItem.note[3], 1)
```

Comment: So you're doing `sleep()` in the main thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thread is deliberately emitting more than one signal to execute the `play()` method in the main thread. Your `play` method must be running for a reasonable amount of time and blocking the main thread (it for instance has a `time.sleep` in it).

You probably need to move the `play` code into the thread as well, but only if the MIDI library you are using is safe to call from a secondary thread. Note that you should also check if the library is thread safe if you plan to call the library from multiple threads.

Comment: It only has to be thread-safe if more than one thread calls functions from the library, or if more than one thread modifies the state of an object managed by the library. If main thread communicates with aux thread only via async signals, it can be safely run in a non-main thread.

Comment: @Schollii I've seen some libraries (not necessarily audio playback ones) state that it must be used only from the main thread and not a secondary thread. I'm not sure why that is, but perhaps because the import (which is usually in the main thread) might do some initialisation? But yes, I should probably clarify what I wrote!

Comment: Interesting, if you can find one such example please post a link, I'd like to find out more. GUI libraries can only be used from main thread, so I suppose there may be others which have functions that must only be called from main thread. But I'd like to know the details of what and why.

Comment: Thank you for the timely responses. Transferring the play() code to run(), I ended up not needing emit at all. I do not know whether this could lead to other issues, but I can at least do some other testing now. Side note: To terminate the thread, I needed to define stop(), in which self.terminate() was called.